# while and if iteration count X even numbers

Tags: java

im new to java and i can't figure it out how to write this program.

Write a program that given a set of numbers by input, sum them. After the 5th even number, stop it. Display the followed sum.

Ok i can check if a number its even and how to print the sum, but i can't understand how to check only 5 even numbers.
I tried with while iteration but don't know hot to write it using proper sintax.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class es04 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n ;
    int sum;
    int even;
    System.out.print("insert numbers:    ");
    n = scan.nextInt();


    even = n % == 0; //dont know where to check even numbers, should it be inside while?
    while (even=5) { 
        System.out.println("sum even numbers"+sum);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where is the increment for even ?

Comment: besides the increment: check what `while (even=5)` is doing...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class es04 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n ;
   int count=0, total=0 ;
   int even;


  while (count < 5) {

             System.out.print("insert number:    ");
             n = scan.nextInt();
             if(n%2==0)
             {
             total=total+n;  count++;
             }
  }
      System.out.println("sum even numbers"+total);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to be doing is continuously poll for numbers as long as your `evenCount` is less than five.

```
while(evenCount < 5) {
    int number = scan.nextInt();
}
```

You then want to check if the number you just got is even or not, and if it is increment your `evenCount`

```
if(number % 2 == 0) {
    evenCount++;
}
```

Regardless of if the number is even or not you want to add it to your sum.

```
sum += number;
```

You should be able to put together your homework from all of this now.

Comment: 2 things: 1) why do you set the $evenCount <5 if the program says stop after 5 even number? 2) why do i want to add any number to the sum and not just the even ?

Comment: 1) Because the way I set it up you will get 5 even numbers, then it will go to the top of the while loop 5 is not less than 5 so it will not execute anymore...

2) Your question was unclear on what is summed, I assumed that it was everything odd or even, if it's only even numbers that you want to sum just move that statement inside the `if(number % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need a counter variable that increments for every even number input.

```
int count = 0;
if(n % 2 == 0) {
 count++;
}
```

Then:

```
if(count == 5){
   stop input
}
```